# Styled Components in React: <Form /> onSubmit handler does not work

Tags: styled-components

The Form Component is of type styled.form`` and is defined outside the component on the bottom of the file. The **issue**: The onSubmit event handler does not work. Official docs don't have anything on onSubmit.

```
   const submitHandler = e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(e) // nothing appears in console
   }


/// ... in JSX:

         <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
            <Input placeholder="YouTube URL" required name="input" onChange={changeHandler} />
            <Button type="submit" >
               <Icon /> <Span>Add Song</Span>
            </Button>
         </Form>

//... styled form defined at the bottom of the file below export default statement:

const Form = styled.form`
   display: flex;
`
```

A **Solution** that I have found is to attach the submitHandler to an onClick event of a button inside a form. I'm not sure about that as I have never in the past used the button for submitHandlers (and I don't think it even works in pure React).

**So, this would work:**

```
<Button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler} >Submit</Button>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in a tiny app based on your code fragment(s) -- `onSubmit` works fine.  Having a complete example would help.

Comment: https://github.com/welschmoor/songplayer-react is the Repo,  /src/components/AddSong.js is the compontent with the form. Delete the onClick from Button to reproduce. Maybe something with my PC, as I didn't really find anyone else having this issue, or some typo which I am blind to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the button. You have the `<Button>` component implemented as a `<div>` styled component. Having `type="submit"` on a `<div>` has no effect as far as the form is concerned. That's why the **submit** event never got fired.

So, you can change your code as follows:

1. `const Button = styled.button`
2. remove `onClick` from the button and change the `onSubmit` simply to `submitHandler`:

```
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Paste YouTube URL here"
          required
          name="input"
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <Button type="submit">
          <Icon /> <Span>Add Song</Span>
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
```

You will see the results in the UI, as the form will start applying validation (because of the `required` attribute on the input), and also in the console where the handler will log.

Comment: You're amazing, thanks!